# React Native. - MacOs - a lot of problems

Tags: android, ios, ruby, xcode, react-native

I having several problems launching Android and Ios simulators on my Mac

I cant create a new project because Ruby is hitting me:

✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing Ruby Gems
error /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:264:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException) from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in` activate_bin_path'
from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `'
✖ Installing Ruby Gems
error Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=macos&platform=android and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
➜  Desktop

About Ruby problems I tried all, install by Brew, cocoapods install, try to update from main website

I tried to solve them via: react-native-doctor but one still not working:

```
Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 33.0.0
```

At least, my Ios simulator still not working too, when I launch my app in Ios it load my simulator but never open my app there.... I tried inside Xcode and it say: DEVICE DONT BOOT

PLEASE HELP!

I tried all I read in Stackoverflow like:

dding a `local.properties` with the content:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/[username]/Library/Android/sdk
```

(And yes the folder exists and is correct, it's the same one set in Android Studio)

Updating the `.zshrc` with:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Comment: If your Mac has an M chip  you should make sure everything is set up such that it's not using Rosetta. There's a guide here for helping set things up for M. Its using Brew to install Ruby. https://medium.com/@davidjasonharding/developing-a-react-native-app-on-an-m1-mac-without-rosetta-29fcc7314d70  and here's something about Homebrew on an M1 https://earthly.dev/blog/homebrew-on-m1/